# Calling Static Functions in JS Class

Tags: javascript, class, static-methods

I'm having trouble calling the static functions within the "Resource" class. Since it is a static function, am I correct trying to call it using the class name and then the name of the function? (ex. Resource.add() - under the AddBtn section in the code below)

Below is the code I have so far:

```
var ResourcesArray = ["Blacksmith", "Farm", "Gold", "Herb", "Quarry", "Vineyard", "Wood"]

class Resource {
    constructor(name, amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount
        this.image = "images/" + this.name + "Icon.png"
    }
    
    static add() {
        this.amount += 1
    }
    subtract() {
        this.amount -= 1
    }
    trade() {
        console.log(this.name)
    }
}

function createNewResourceClassInstance() {
    for (i = 0; i < ResourcesArray.length; i++) {
        return ResourcesArray.map(res => new Resource(res, 0));
    }
}

function createResourceCards() {
    let resources = createNewResourceClassInstance();
    console.log(resources);

    for (i = 0; i < resources.length; i++){
        AddBtn = document.createElement("button")
        AddBtn.setAttribute("id", resources[i].name + "AddBtn")
        AddBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success add-btn")
        AddBtn.setAttribute("onClick", Resource.add())
        AddBtn.innerText = "+"
    }
    
}
createResourceCards()
```

I don't receive any errors in Chrome Console when the page loads or when the AddBtn is clicked.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How it can be static if it affects the class attribute?

Comment: I don't think it should be static. It looks to me like you made it static because you couldn't figure out how to call it. Probably you should remove the static keyword and change your question to be "How do I call this `add()` method from my `onClick()` handler?

Comment: ah ok, thanks. The Static option is what I came across during my research on w3schools and it said you can call it with the class name ".function()". I can edit the question